# Two questions regarding convergence almost everywhere:

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For the purpose of this post $\mathcal{L}$
  denotes the Lebesgue $\sigma$
 -algebra, $\mathcal{B}$
  denotes the Borel $\sigma$
 -algebra and $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue Measure.

I'm trying prove the following two claims:

**1.** Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
  be Lebesgue measurable with $\lambda\left(A\right)=\infty$
  and let $f_{n}:\left(A,\mathcal{L}\right)\to\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}\right)$
  be a sequence of borel-measurable functions  such that $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere on $A$ (relative to $\lambda$). Show that for each $M>0$
  there is a $\lambda$-measurable $A_{M}\subseteq A$
  such that $\lambda\left(A_{M}\right)>M$
  and $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A_{M}$.

**My Thoughts:** This is obviously similar to Egoroff's theorem and I have a feeling it could be used in the proof. I suppose from Egoroff's Theorem given $B\subseteq A$
  such that $\lambda\left(B\right)<\infty$
  for any $\varepsilon>0$
  I can find a subset $C\subseteq B$
  such that $\lambda\left(C\right)<\varepsilon$
  and $f_{n}$
  converges uniformly on $B\backslash C$
 . I don't have a good idea on how to use this to prove the intended claim though.

**2.** Let $f_{n}:\left(\left[0,1\right],\mathcal{L}\right)\to\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}\right)$
  be a sequence of Borel-measurable functions. Prove that there is a sequence $\left\{ c_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$
  of positive real numbers such that $\frac{f_{n}}{c_{n}}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$
 almost everywhere on $\left[0,1\right]$. [Hint: use Borel-Cantelli's Lemma] .

**My Thoughts:** As per the hint my line of thinking was to try and find a sequence of sets $\left\{ B_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$
  such ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda\left(B_{n}\right)<\infty}$
  and $$\limsup B_{n}=\left\{ x\in\left[0,1\right]\:|\:\lim\limits _{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{f_{n}\left(x\right)}{c_{n}}\right)\neq0\right\}$$ 
 This given some choice of $\left\{ c_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$
  which works. Unfortunately I have no idea what that choice might be. As for the $B_{n}$'s
  I imagine they would have to be something of the form $$\left\{ x\in\left[0,1\right]\,|\,\left|\frac{f_{n}\left(x\right)}{c_{n}}\right|>\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$  but I'm not really sure if this works.

ּ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof of the second claim:** To find an appropriate sequence $\{c_n\}$, fix $n$, and define $B_k=\{ x : \frac1k|f_n(x)|\geq\frac1n \}$. Then $B_k \searrow \emptyset$, and $\lambda(B_k)\rightarrow 0$. Therefore, there exists $k_n\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $\lambda(B_{k_n})<2^{-n}$.

Letting $c_n=k_n$, and $A_n=B_{k_n}$, we have (by Borel-Cantelli) $$\lambda (\limsup A_n)=0.$$ Letting $$L:=\{x : \lim\frac1{c_n}f_n(x)=0\},$$ we note that $L^\complement\subseteq \limsup A_n$. Hence, $\lambda(L^\complement)=0$, and $\frac1{c_n} f_n\overset{\text{a.e.}}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof of the first claim:** First we'll show that for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$
  there is an $A_{M}\subseteq A$
  such that $\lambda\left(A_{M}\right)>M$
 , define:$\mathcal{A}=\left\{ \lambda\left(B\right)\;|\: B\subseteq A\quad\lambda\left(B\right)<\infty\right\}$ 
 Now given $N\in\mathbb{N}$
  we know that $\lambda\left(A\cap\left[-N,N\right]\right)\leq2N$
  and thus $A\cap\left[-N,N\right]\in\mathcal{A}$
  and we can see that:$$\infty=\lambda\left(A\right)=\lim_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{\lambda}\left(A\cap\left[-N,N\right]\right)\leq\sup\left(\mathcal{A}\right)$$
 Thus for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$
  there is an $A_{M}\subseteq A$
  such that $M<\lambda\left(A_{M}\right)<\infty$
 . Now given $M>0$
  and $\varepsilon>0$
  we have a subset $A_{M+\varepsilon}\subseteq A$
  such that $M+\varepsilon<\lambda\left(A_{M}\right)<\infty$
 . From Egoroff's Theorem there is a $B\subseteq A_{M+\varepsilon}$
  such that $\lambda\left(B\right)<\varepsilon$
  and $f_{n}$
  converges uniformly to $f$
  on $A_{M+\varepsilon}\backslash B$
  and additionally $$\lambda\left(A_{M}\backslash B\right)=\lambda\left(A_{M}\right)-\lambda\left(B\right)>\left(M+\varepsilon\right)-\varepsilon=M$$
  Thus $A_{M}=A_{M+\varepsilon}\backslash B$
  meets the requirements of the claim.

Still working on the latter claim.